# Attachments Overrides existing while adding from VendorMaint graph

Tags: acumatica

I am importing data and documents from third party application into Acumatica.

After importing, I am creating Vendor dynamically using below code along with attachments.

```
VendorMaint graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<VendorMaint>();
VendorR row1 = null;
row1 = new VendorR();
row1.AcctName = VendorName;
row1.NoteID = noteid;      // Existing - GUID created while importing
graph.BAccount.Update(row1);
```

If attachment already exists then it should update instead of duplicating.

In this case if Vendor already exists with files attached, then my code overrides these attachments and remove all previous files attached to that existing vendor.

I want to add the attachment instead of override the existing attachment. Any suggestion?

Comment: What is relationship between Vendor and attachement? 1 to 1 or 1 to many? If 1 to many, I can't see which part of code analyzes quantity of relations?

Comment: Vendor and Attachment has 1 to many relationship. I am not attaching multiple attachment instead I am just attaching only one. Here I am referring to existing Vendor which already has previous attachments and now I am adding one more. Line row1.NoteID = noteid, is the code which is actually replacing the all attachment instead of adding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for the issue. Below code helps to create a new attachment and does not override any existing attachments for an existing Vendor.

```
 // Getting the FileID of the attached file from DACClass
 UploadFile uf = PXSelectJoin<UploadFile,
    InnerJoin<NoteDoc, On<NoteDoc.fileID, Equal<UploadFile.fileID>>,
    InnerJoin<DACClass, On<DACClass.noteID, Equal<NoteDoc.noteID>>>>, 
    Where<DACClass.noteID, Equal<Required<DACClass.noteID>>>>.Select(this, noteid);

 if (uf != null)
 {
      PXNoteAttribute.SetFileNotes(graph.BAccount.Cache, graph.BAccount.Current, uf.FileID.Value);

      NoteDoc doc = new NoteDoc();
      doc.NoteID = uf.FileID.Value;
      doc.FileID = new Guid();
      graph.BAccount.Cache.Insert(doc);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use insert method of view:

```
VendorMaint graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<VendorMaint>();
var row1 = new VendorR();
row1 = graph.BAccount.Insert(row1);
if (row1 == null) // already inserted or wasn't able to insert
{
      //some logic with newly created vendor
}
else
{
      //some logic with existed
}
row1.AcctName = "vendor name";
row1.NoteID = noteid;      // Existing - GUID created while importing
graph.BAccount.Update(row1);
```

Comment: Hi Yura,
Sorry for the confusion if any. 
Creating Vendor is ok for me and I can check for duplicate also. The problem is with File attachment with that vendor. If the vendor already exists with already attached few files then I want to update that vendor with one more file attachment.

Comment: You have written "If vendor already exists then it should update instead of duplicating". What should be updated? Vendor? Maybe you can edit your question?

Comment: Updated the question. Hope it is now more meaningful.